# Вывод записей с базы данных (redbeanphp)

Tags: sql, redbeanphp

Вообщем, знаю отлично php, но с таким встречаюсь впервые. Мне нужно обновлять записи с турнира... после первой записи выводит с условием те записи, которые были до этого... перепробовал всё, но всё тщетно.
Вот код:

```
    function update_mix_winner($data)
{
    $query_string = $_GET['q'];
    $query_array = explode('/', $query_string);
    $id = $query_array[1];
    $tour = R::load('tournaments',$id); 
    $versus = R::load('versus',$data['vid']);
    $versus->winner=$data['winner']; 
    $versus->loser=$data['loser']; 
    R::store($versus);
    $wteam = R::findAll('teams','rounds_id = "2" AND tn = 1 AND tournaments_id = ?', [$tour->id]);
    $lteam = R::findAll('teams','rounds_id = "2" AND tn = 2 AND tournaments_id = ?', [$tour->id]);
    print '<pre>Винеры <br>';
    foreach($wteam as $w)
    {
        print '<br>'.$w->players->users->name;
        R::exec( 'UPDATE `players` SET `w`=`w`+1 WHERE `id` ="'.$w->players->id.'"');
    }
    print 'Лузеры <br>';
    foreach($lteam as $l)
    {
        print '<br>'.$l->players->users->name;
        R::exec( 'UPDATE `players` SET `l`=`l`+1 WHERE `id` ="'.$l->players->id.'"');
    }
    print_r($data);

    if(count($tour->withCondition('rounds_id = ? AND winner = "played"',[$data['round']])->ownVersusList) == 0)
    {
        next_mix_round($data);
    }
    unset($wteam);
    unset($lteam);
}
```

Comment: Проще сделать в самой БД: `UPDATE players P
  JOIN teams T ON T.id=P.id
   SET w=w+(T.tn=1), l=l+(T.tn=2)
 WHERE rounds_id=2 and tournaments_id = ? and tn in(1,2)` (вариант для MySQL, в других диалектах сравнение T.tn=1 не дает на выходе 0 или 1 и должно быть заменено другими формулами или case). Так же настораживает, что id игрока в  teams называется id, если это не так (хотя php код намекает на это) следует поправить условие соединения в ON. Так же само наличие полей l и w нарушает принципы проектирования БД, эти значения по любому игроку всегда можно вычислить по teams.

Comment: @Mike, это лишь прототип, мне надо сделать это всё в функции обязательно! и может я уже слишком дурачок, но я не понимаю почему у меня запись идёт с прошлого раунда... То что идёт rounds_*id* это связь с таблицой

Comment: Ну вы же пишите $l->players->id это не похоже на rounds_id. М зачем вам обязательно делать это в php функции средствами php, да еще и циклами по отдельной записи ? Один запрос SQL отработает в 20 раз быстрее. А вызывать вы его так же будете из функции

Comment: @Mike, не могли бы сказать, как лучше это сделать?

Comment: хм. что не так в моем первом запросе ? он должен выполнить в точности все, что делает ваша функция. Ему надо только значение tournaments_id передать. Ну и возможно все таки заменить условие в ON.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо ;)